# Declare dynamic variable from array list angular js

Tags: angularjs

I created an array.

**JS code**

```
$scope.type = ["status", "category", "subCategory", "room"];
```

I want to use `array` item as variable. I have to create dynamically. Later I will add a dynamic value. For example when I use $scope.type[0]
variable have to be $scope.status How can I do?

Comment: here what you want to try ?

Comment: I want to use as $scope. $scope.type[0]. But doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using the bracket notation.

```
$scope[$scope.type[0]] = "dynamic value";
```

To create for every item in array --

```
$scope.type.forEach(function(value){
 $scope[value] = "any dynamic value"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this your need ?

```
$scope[$scope.type[0]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try below.

```
$scope.status = $scope.type[0];
$scope.category= $scope.type[1];
$scope.subCategory= $scope.type[2];
```

Comment: He said he wanted to add them (new ones) dynamically. How do you plan on adding a new `$scope` variable without knowing what it will be in advance?